# Increase the contrast for the "pressed" election buttons

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-election, user-experience

I have reasonably good sight, but I'm still having problems recognizing which button is pressed in [the election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1). I know there's a list on the right side, but it's not anchored and disappears when you scroll the page down. That leaves the buttons as the only way to see your current selections.

Could we add some contrast between those two shades of blue?

---

In a related problem, it seems that the "selected" state is inconsistently used.

Here are the button stylings with none of the choices selected:

[image]

And here are the button stylings with the 3rd choice selected:

[image]

Also the text would better look vertically centered.

Comment: I think the buttons you didn't click on should be the same color as they were initially. As it is, it looks like they are disabled, but they aren't. I suggest changing the button that's selected instead, maybe coloring it in green ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JNrJ.png)) (I'm not sure green is the best color, maybe another color would be better).

Comment: I agree; this is a problem. I've noticed it before, but it didn't bother me enough to motivate reporting it. Thanks for taking the time to write this up! Maybe add a checkmark to the side of the selected option, like we do for accepted answers? That would solve the usability problem, while also maintaining a consistent feel. (In fact, giving the buttons a "disabled"/"grayed" appearance is sending the wrong message, because clicking on one of them is how you *change* your choice!)

Comment: Or something like [that](https://i.imgur.com/dKBfkSD.png) which is more colorblind compliant

Comment: I would actually prefer that I see which I have pressed already on the candidates where I didn't vote yet...

Comment: That's interesting, for me the list on the right side *is* anchored when I scroll the page down.  It disappears off the bottom when I scroll the page all the way *up*, to make room for the voting instructions, but otherwise I can always see it. On Firefox 59. That said I am wholly in favor of changing the visual feedback on the buttons.